# how to get access to the messages that we send itself to telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have seen telegram bot documentation and I know it has `getUpdates` endpoint which sends information about the messages we type and send into the bot.

so when `webhook` is disabled and I manually type some messages into bot I can get those messages from `https://api.telegram.org/<token>/getUpdates`

```json
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":301215553,
"message":{"message_id":31,"from":{"id":1235349470,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"XYZ","username":"ABC","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":1235349470,"first_name":"XYZ","username":"ABC","type":"private"},"date":1669990759,"text":"/help","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":5,"type":"bot_command"}]}}
```

but I couldn't get messages that I send to bot itself using `sendMessage` endpoint `https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=-1001659408929&text=my sample text`

After the above request when I want to get access the message `my Sample text` which I sent to bot itself I couldn't list that with `getUpdates` endpoint.

So is there any way to get that information from the telegram or telegram didn't support for that type of messages?

So basically messages that are incoming to bot is not get listed in `getUpdates`.

Answer (score -1):

Each method listed in the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) has a return value that you can access. [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) returns the resulting `Message`.

Comment: Yes `sendMessage` return the response itself but let's say after sometime I want to access that message that was sent via `sendMessage` I think there is no way for that.

Comment: You'll have to store the returned response.